# Call a dynamic python function after the webpage is loaded in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

I have a function in python which will return one of many Image URLs. I would like to implement a button on a webpage made with django which will change the image's source to the returned value. The issue I've run into is that django template tags are only accessible when the page is rendered, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008908/use-django-template-tags-in-jquery-javascript). Since the real code cannot be recreated in javascript, is there a workaround to get access to the python function's return data every time the button is pressed?

Here is some code to clarify my question:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    def get_image_url():
        if(random.randint(0,1)):
            return 'http://img1.jpg'
        else:
            return 'http://img2.jpg'
```

This is how I would want it to behave in javascript, if it were possible.

```
function updateImage(){
    document.getElementById("testImage").src="{{ foo.get_image_url }}";
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have to use AJAX for this. You can define a Django view which returns a JSON message with something like:

```
{
    status: "ok",
    url: "img1.jpg"
}
```

So in your code, you can define an event handler (in JavaScript) with something like this:

```
// Attach a listener to a button for a click event,
document.getElementById("testImageButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // This URL returns the above JSON.
    xhr.open("GET", "/images/random"); 
    xhr.onloadend = function() {
         // Should have error handling in case response does not return correctly.
         var imageResult = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
         if(imageResult['status'] == 'ok') {
             // update the image src
             document.getElementById("testImage").setAttribute("src", imageResult['url']);
         }
    }
    xhr.send()
})
```

So the only "dynamic function part" is whatever is inside your Django view function.