# Sending a DELETE request from a form in Django

Tags: jquery, django

I am trying to send a DELETE request from a form in Django taking help from jQuery referring following link below;

https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/put-and-delete-http-requests-with-django-and-jquery/

What I have are the following scripts;

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      id : 'delete',
      headers : {'X_METHODOVERRIDE': 'DELETE'}
    });
  });
</script>
```

(I intend to have) acting on the following form;

```
<form method="post" id="delete" name="delete" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

And the following middleware;

```
from django.http import QueryDict

class HttpPostTunnelingMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META.has_key('HTTP_X_METHODOVERRIDE'):
            http_method = request.META['HTTP_X_METHODOVERRIDE']
            if http_method.lower() == 'put':
                request.method  = 'PUT'
                request.META['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'PUT'
                request.PUT = QueryDict(request.body)
            if http_method.lower() == 'delete':
                request.method  = 'DELETE'
                request.META['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'DELETE'
                request.DELETE = QueryDict(request.body)
        return None
```

I have it added to the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES list in my settings.py;

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'stationrunner.middleware.HttpPostTunnelingMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

It's the 3rd entry, before the `CsrfViewMiddleware` taking words of @Daniel Roseman into consideration.

And finally in my class based view I have the delete method delete the corresponding object;

```
class StationHome(View):
    .
    .
    .
    def post(self,request, pk):
        station = Station.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form = StationForm(request.POST, instance=station)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home_station",
                                                kwargs={'pk':pk},
                                            )
                                    )
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Form Invalid!")

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        Station.objects.get(pk=pk).delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse("list_create_station")                      
            )
    .
    .
```

I expect the middleware and the script make a DELETE request sent to the view but things ain't flying. A POST method itself is being sent. Django is finding an invalid form and gives me the response; "Form Invalid!" (`else: return HttpResponse("Form Invalid!"`)

**Update**

I have updated the script to look like;

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#delete').submit.function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var station_id = {{ station.id }}
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/station/' + station_id,
        headers: {'X_METHODOVERRIDE': 'DELETE'}
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have the object passed to the template as `station` and I have used the Django template language inside the script (`var station_id = {{ station.id }}`) taking inspiration from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6008968/4672736

The result is the same :/

**Update**

Debugging js found that the browser wasn't finding the jQuery file. Now with static files properly configured and also, the csrf protection set with help of jquery.cookie.js I have the below code in my template;

```
<script src="{% static "stationrunner/jquery-1.11.3.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "stationrunner/jquery.cookie.js" %}"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
      // these HTTP methods don't require CSRF protection
      return(/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if(!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
      }
    });
    $('#delete').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url 'home_station' station.id %}',
        headers: {'X_METHODOVERRIDE': 'DELETE'}
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now I have no errors on the front end but success ain't met yet. The submission of the form gets me a `200` response instead of `302`.

Is this expected with an AJAX request?

It seems the request is not yet getting passed to the view as a delete request.

I tried adding `success: function(){alert('Object deleted!')}` to `$.ajax` and the alert do pop up.

**Update**

The final hurdle was that I had to use dashes in the custom header passed instead of underscores. I changed `headers: { 'X_METHODOVERRIDE': 'DELETE' }` to `headers: { 'X-METHODOVERRIDE': 'DELETE' }`. The letters need not be passed in capital letters too. Django will anyway convert them to capitals. So `x-methodoverride` or `x-MeThODoveRrIDE` for that matter is fine too. I don't know why dashes instead of underscores though. I figured that out as the other headers passed were carrying dashes and not underscores.

Earlier the middleware wasn't finding the key `HTTP_X_METHODOVERRIDE`. Now  it does and my view gets a delete request :)

Comment: Can you post also the code of your class based view?

Comment: your javascript is still wrong, it should be `$('#delete').submit(function(e) {`. I suppose you'll have errors in your javascript console. Are you using Firebug on Firefox or Chrome Devtools to debug your client side code? You should... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your javascript code. You are submitting the form as a regular POST request and not using the $.ajax javascript code at all.

You should include jquery in a separate script tag, like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Then in another script tag you put your code:

```
<script>
    $('#delete').submit(function(e) {
        // do NOT submit the form as a regular POST request
        e.preventDefault();
        var object_to_delete_id = $('#object_to_delete_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/your-view-url/' + object_to_delete_id,
            success: function() {
                alert('Object deleted!')
            },
            headers: { 'X_METHODOVERRIDE': 'DELETE' }
        });
    });
<script>
```

Here I'm assuming that you have the id of the object you want to delete in a form field like this:

```
<form method="post" id="delete" name="delete" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" id="object_to_delete_id" />
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Please pay attention to Django CSRF protection on your Ajax call, you should write some javascript to set your CSRF cookie value in the request, as explained in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Also returning a HttpResponseRedirect to an Ajax call doesn't make much sense, because the browser will not redirect to that page as it would happen with a regular POST request.

I'd suggest to study a little bit more how jquery and Ajax requests work, before digging in more complex examples like this. ;)

Comment: You're an angel :). Started using devtools and  it says it is unable to find the jQuery file. I have it right along with the template file. In the same directory. I'd read in w3 schools tutorial to do so. Hence. Where shall I change it to?

Comment: Just to show you; `ls templates/`;
`audio_files.html     home_audio_file.html   jquery-1.11.3.js
auth                 home_audio_file.html~  list_channels.html
create_channel.html  home_station.html      stations.html
deny_user.html       home_station.html~
deny_user.html~      home_user.html` You can find the corresponding template file "`home_station.html`" and the jquery file "`jquery-1.11.3.js`" here

Comment: To simplify things I updated my answer to take jquery from a CDN on the internet (assuming your client have internet access). But I'd suggest you to have a look on how [Django manages static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/). You cannot just put them in templates directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ended up assuming! Have read and configured static files now. Now the form doesn't get posted. It tells me `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (FORBIDDEN)`. I assume it might be about the js you earlier told about, needed to set CSRF cookie value in the AJAX request. Lemme read and try figure out.

Comment: That's done. Now the request is getting a `200` response. It doesn't seem to have gone into the view. Is `200` the expected response with an AJAX request? Please see my update.

Comment: Yes, the 200 response is what you expect, because Ajax is still an http request and 200 means "success". Please check in devtools the URL of the request you made (in the network tab, it should be a XHR request), and check the urls.py of tour Django project to see if they match.

Comment: They do match. I have `Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/station/2`, the right URL. I have `X_METHODOVERRIDE:DELETE` too. Also I can find a response there, "Form Invalid". It's what I have as response in the view for a post request if form is invalid. In short the view still gets a post request not a delete. I must assume the middleware is not doing it's job right. Please tell me this too. So with an Ajax request the response just won't come up in the page? The page is supposed to remain?

Comment: Try to move the middleware inclusion in the last place of your settings.py, as it was in my blog post. You can also place some logging in the middleware to see what is doing. You should really study a little bit more about Ajax, because is a building block of modern web apps, you can think of it as a way to interact with a server without having to reload the entire page every time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78974/discussion-between-afzal-sh-and-baxeico).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the ordering of your middleware. When the request is received, the middleware is processed in the order that it is specified in the settings. In your case, that means the CSRF middleware is run first, sees that the request is a POST without a CSRF token, and raises the error.

Try moving your HttpPostTunnelingMiddleware before the CsrfViewMiddleware.

Comment: That's not it. What I get is the response as a result of `if form.valid: so_and_so else: HttpResponse("Form Invalid")`. I tried as you said but result is the same. And I tried taking out the csrf_token and gets `Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` error. I suppose maybe you thought this was the error I was getting. Maybe not. Anyways, the ordering of middlewares doesn't seem to be the problem