# PUT and DELETE Django

Tags: python, django

I relatively new in django and python and now for a couple of days i'm trying to figure how to send PUT and DELETE requests throught django forms.

I found this topics:
https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/put-and-delete-http-requests-with-django-and-jquery/

[Sending a DELETE request from a form in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461839/sending-a-delete-request-from-a-form-in-django)

But the way this topics solve this problem seams not easy for me. So question is - is there are any easy way to send PUT and DELETE requests throught forms in Django.

For now i have this:

views.py

```
class AllRoutes(View):

model = Schedule
template_name = 'trains_schedule/all_routes.html'

def get(self,request,train_id=None):
    if train_id:
        train = Schedule.objects.get(pk=int(train_id))
        context = {'train':train}
    else:
        context = {'schedule_list':Schedule.objects.all()}
    return render(request,'trains_schedule/all_routes.html',context)

def delete(self,request,train_id=None):
    route = get_object_or_404(Schedule, pk=train_id)
    response = u'Successful delete route {}'.format(route.display_name())
    route.delete()
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^trains/(?P<train_id>[0-9]+)?$', views.AllRoutes.as_view(), name='trains')]
```

all_routes.html

```
{% if schedule_list %}
<h3>{{ "List of all train routes" }}</h3>
<ul>
{% for train_route in schedule_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'trains' train_route.id %}">{{ train_route.display_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p></p>
{% endif %}

{% if train %}
<h1>{{ train.train }}</h1>

<h3>{{ "Route info" }}</h3>
{{ train.display_train }}

<h3>{{ "Train info" }}</h3>
{{train.display_train_info}}

<form  method="delete">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
{% else %}
<p></p>
{% endif %}
```

Now it works this way:

- /trains/ show list of all trains routes and provide links to every route
- /trains/12 - get() in views.py got route id and show information about this route

And i want that when i pressing "delete" - view receive DELETE request.

I end with doing it this way:

```
<form  method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input id="action_id" type="hidden" name="action" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

and in views.py i add handling of post request with action_id =="Delete"

But i want to make real DELETE and PUT request, not parse the POST request to understand that i need to do - delete or change route or add new one.

I understand that i need to change this part:

```
<form  method="delete">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

But i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Are you asking how to do delete or edits properly in Django or do you want to implement a proper rest interface? The answer will be different as for a a rest interface, the best is to use a third party package

Comment: I just want to know that is the easiest way to send PUT and DELETE request from frontend side. I read about REST framwork - understand a lot but same problem -  dont understand how to send PUT and DELETE request from frontend side.

Comment: It really sound like you read that you use PUT and DELETE to change and delete data, but unless you are developing an API, you can just use the proper Django way to create edit and delete views. So, rather that trying to use words you may not understand, maybe explain what is your end goal

Comment: Ok, i'll explain - i was on the interview on intern-developer position, one of my task was - make django service, result -  http://smosker.pythonanywhere.com/schedule/ i should create application in REST way, but on frontend i should use pure HTML - but i can't figure how to send PUT and DELETE requests and made only POST form requests with hidden value for PUT and DELETE requests. But my interwievers told me i should do it another way.

Comment: Pure HTML? No Javascript allowed?

Comment: As i understand it was allowed but they claim that it is possible to do on pure HTML. Am i understand correct that in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461839/sending-a-delete-request-from-a-form-in-django they use Javascript? Or how i should do it with Javascript?

Answer (score 23):

According to the [HTML standard](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp), the valid methods for form are `GET` and `POST`. So you can't do like this `<form method="delete">`.
However Django correct handle 'PUT' and 'DELETE' (and all others) http methods.

```
from django.views.generic import View


class TestView(View):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']

    def put(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Hello, i'm %s!" % self.request.method

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Hello, i'm %s!" % self.request.method


Hello, i'm PUT!
[06/Apr/2016 23:44:51] "PUT /de/teacher/test/ HTTP/1.1"
Hello, i'm DELETE!
[06/Apr/2016 23:57:15] "DELETE /de/teacher/test/ HTTP/1.1"
```

You can make PUT and DELETE http calls thought the ajax.
If you need to use it form you can do some workaround:

```
<form action="{% url 'teacher:test' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>


class TestView(View):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        method = self.request.POST.get('_method', '').lower()
        if method == 'put':
            return self.put(*args, **kwargs)
        if method == 'delete':
            return self.delete(*args, **kwargs)
        return super(TestView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Hello, i'm %s!" % self.request.POST.get('_method')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Hello, i'm %s!" % self.request.POST.get('_method')


Hello, i'm delete!
[07/Apr/2016 00:10:53] "POST /de/teacher/test/ HTTP/1.1"
Hello, i'm put!
[07/Apr/2016 00:10:31] "POST /de/teacher/test/ HTTP/1.1"
```

It's not the real `PUT` but you can use the same interface for forms and ajax/api calls.

Comment: Thanks, so i understand correctly - there is no way to send PUT and DELETE request on pure HTML?

Comment: Just commenting that this was how I found to limit the http methods from specific views.  I have a view where I want to allow someone to GET, POST or DELETE but not PUT or PATCH.