# Using request.body in Django compared to nodejs for building restful apis

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, django, express

I have just begun learning the Django framework, and my goal is too take this knowledge and use it to build a rest api. (I have considered using django-rest framework, but my job requires specifically Django). I have already learned a medium amount of nodejs, and for this I use express. I use the req.body to enable users to enter some information. In Django, how would I use this req.body property to allow a user to type information. This is purely for backend purposes (no frontend included). For example, sending a post request, and setting parameters.

Comment: I think this could be an interesting question, as a comparison between the Express and Django `request` objects. I think we need a little bit more info on what you mean by "allow a user to type information" first. Do you mean sending data to your endpoint, for example using a post request or as parameters in a query string?

Comment: Yep! When a user sends parameters as a post request, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Both Express and Django endpoints receive a reference to the request object. The APIs are of course different. Here is a rough mapping:

- Query string parameters (`https://example.com/?foo=bar`):

  - [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query): `request.query.foo`
  - [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET): `request.GET["foo"]`
- Post data (posting `foo=bar`):

  - [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body): Depends on your middleware, but typically `req.body.foo`.
  - [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST): `request.POST["foo"]`
- Figuring out the request method is the same in both: `request.method`, which is a string like `"POST"` or `"GET"`.

Comment: Thanks bro! It was the post data I was looking for. So are request.POST and request.body identical as in they do the same functionality ?

Comment: Also can you put and delete data, as in the equivalent to posting data with django and express

Comment: @NodeNinja08 your first question I would say yes, kind of. There are details that differ but basically they work very similarly.

The second question is harder to answer in a short way. Check this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36462516/98057

Comment: No problem! Check out Django's excellent documentation if you haven't already. It will probably be faster for you than asking questions on SO, most of the time. You should of course ask if you're stuck! Happy hacking.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.body
```

in express is equivalent to

```
request.POST
```

in django